# MongoDb CommandFailureException error

Tags: mongodb

I run into the following MongoDB error after change my application data related code and altering data yesterday. After reverting the code and dropping data based, the error don't occur somehow. Today, I run into the same error when I run unit tests while the application is running fine.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:52391" , "errmsg" : "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected string" , "code" : 16722 , "ok" : 0.0}
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:140)
at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:464)
at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.runScript(MongeezDao.java:124)
at org.mongeez.commands.Script.run(Script.java:32)
at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:53)
at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:42)
at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:40)
```

How to clean up this error?

Comment: Do you have the command that was run?>

Comment: Do you mean a MongoDB client? If so, no. I don't see any other DB access other than my app and unit tests if I start them. I get this error regardless whether the application is running or not.

Comment: Hmm, the command is definitely from your app (you can see the eval throwing the exception) but the question is which line is causing it, it seems the Java exception doesn't really want to say too much about it. Can you turn on profiling and looking in the profile collection when this happens? It should log the error http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/profile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have a bad script in one of your Mongeez database migration files. Since Mongeez won't run changesets it already applied again, the exception won't occur unless the changeset with the error was not applied yet.